# php equivalent to $.get

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-like

I had a fine solution with:

```
$.get('getdbstuff.php?type=meta,'.$var_id, function(data){ 
    $(data).appendTo("head");)
}
```

But that is javascript and it doesn't get executed by the facebook scraper. 
Is there some php equivalent to $.get the getdbstuff.php file loaded.
to load meta tags into the header of my index.php...?

Thanks

Comment: file_get_contents? curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Depending on if you want to go through the web server, just get the contents or execute the contents locally, it would be one of

1. `echo file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/path/file.php?params')`
2. `echo file_get_contents('file.php')` or
3. `include('file.php')`

First one does it the same way AJAX call does it, going through the web server. Second one outputs the contents of the file without executing, probably not what you want, and the last one executes php code without the HTTP call. First one is the closest match to what you do now.

Answer (score 1):

There's whole extension in PHP dedicated to this called [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

But you also may use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (I wouldn't because it relies on configuration to [allow URL `fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in php that paralels jquery, its called [querypath](http://querypath.org/). With it, you can select any DOM element in any external page.
It is straightforward. You choose DOM elements the same way as in jquery.